# search for exact string value in different json files with exact name

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a directory structure like the one given below.

```
       main folder
      /     |     \
folder1  folder2 folder3 ...
```

and in all of these folders have the same file data21.json

My goal is to search for specific string value (like '0d92c8d2-5a57-4c20-9ad7-cbe4fbf51615') in all these .json file and if found in one of them just stop searching, else print false.
I could do this only for one file with this

```
    pipeline_id = '0d92c8d2-5a57-4c20-9ad7-cbe4fbf51615'
    found = False
    if pipeline_id in open('dir1/data21.json').read():
       found = True
    pprint(found)
```

Just cannot find how to search in all /directory/anydirectory/data21.json

Comment: just list all the folders with `os.listdir(path_of_main_folder)` and create the new path to open the json in a for.

Comment: For example my main folder has 4 folders in it, and those 4 folders have data21.json file in them. I need to search my string value in all of them and if it has been found even in one of that json files, it must stop searching.
I need to write path like this /main_folder/*/data21.json and `if pipeline_id in open('main_folder/*/data21.json').read():
   found = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will elaborate my comment. This code will go through all the items inside your `main folder` and check what you want.

```
pipeline_id = '0d92c8d2-5a57-4c20-9ad7-cbe4fbf51615'
#list all the dirs inside the main folder
found = False
main_folder_path = "main_folder" #this will change depending from where you call your script
for dir_name in os.listdir(main_folder_path):  
    dir_path = main_folder_path+"/"+dir_name+"/data21.json"
    if pipeline_id in open(dir_path).read():
       found = True
       break
pprint(found)
```

You may also need to check if the `dir_name` is a directory as you want or a file if you have them mixed inside `main_folder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `os.walk` -

```
import os

BASE_FOLDER = './main'
pipeline_id = '0d92c8d2-5a57-4c20-9ad7-cbe4fbf51615'
found = False

    for r,d,f in os.walk(BASE_FOLDER):
        for file_ in f:
            if file_ == 'data21.json':
                if pipeline_id in open(os.path.join(r, file_)).read():
                    found = True
                    break
        if found:
            break

    print(found)
```